# Dealing with XML namespaces in JavaScript (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-namespaces

I am building a tree (for SOAP) using DOM. I would like read the following info at a certain node:

- Is an XML namespace already "imported" into the document (with `xmlns:blah="http://...`) - knowing the `http://...` part.
- What moniker (in the above example `blah`) used.

Is there any way **other than** the manual: to walk chain of ancestors and iterate on attribute nodes, find any starting with `xmlns:` checking the value and if match return the rest of the attribute name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside the usual methods such as `document.getElementsByTagName`, DOM offers their namespaced versions: `document.getElementsByTagNameNS`

Such methods take the namespace URL as their first argument.

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://...', 'abc');
```

By the way, using the regular methods, the elements might be available as…

```
document.getElementsByTagName('xmlns\\:abc');
```

This works for me in case of a HTML DOM even without "importing" any namespace.

**Update:**

The method OP was looking for is `document.lookupPrefix('http://...')`

Comment: My problem is to find namesapces already imported (so I can import it if it is not already in the document). I have no knowledge about any tag names. - In other words I ofc. know the name of the tag I would like to insert but nothing guarantees that some other tag is not already used from the namesapce and thus the namesapce already imported.

Comment: Oh, right. I read the question wrong. Have you tried `doc.lookupPrefix('http://...')`?